# Magento 2 How to Override Cart/Item/default.phtml file in my Custom module

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, overrides, default

**I create Default.phtml file in Vdcstore/QuantityDropdown/View/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

## Hello

**I Create checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml file in Vdcstore/QuantityDropdown/View/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**

```
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Vdcstore\QuantityDropdown::cart/item/default.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**I create checkout_cart_index.xml file in  Vdcstore/QuantityDropdown/View/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

checkout.cart.item.renderers.override

But Not Working. No effect When I Run a code plz Give me a Solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check The Below Code

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Vdcstore_QuantityDropdown::cart/item/default.phtml" />
```

Correct "Vdcstore\QuantityDropdown" to "Vdcstore_QuantityDropdown"

**Check the Other Solution**

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vdcstore_QuantityDropdown::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-override-cart-item-default-phtml-in-magento-2/) worked great for me